# How to get DB resource knowing DB name?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

I have database name.
I need to get db resource. 
How? One option I see is to execute `Config.Databases:List` query and iterate over results till I find required name. After that open db by path and get the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only name of the database, you should before get a directory, because SYS.Database works only with directory path.

```
set dbName="TEST"
if ##Class(Config.Databases).Exists(dbName,.dbconfobj) {
  Set dbObj=##class(SYS.Database).%OpenId(dbconfobj.Directory)
  Set resourceName = dbObj.ResourceName
}
```

Database directory also you could get in this way

```
if ##Class(Config.Databases).Get("TEST1",.props) {
  write $get(props("Directory"))
}
```

Or directory for default database for current namespace

```
set directory=$zu(12,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open database with `Set dbObj=##class(SYS.Database).%OpenId("USER")` and then get db resource as `dbObj.ResourceName`. [SYS.Database docs](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=SYS.Database) and [Config.Databases docs](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=Config.Databases).

Comment: in this code `##class(SYS.Database).%OpenId("USER")`, USER - is not a name for database it is a default path and default directory for mgr. Here should be defined full path to database, not name.